# ES6 block-scoped variable definition as condition

Tags: javascript, variables, ecmascript-6

In C++ you can do

```
if (MyClass* obj = MyClass::getInstance()) { ... }
```

In JavaScript, there were only function-scoped variables, so following statement wouldn't make sense

```
if (var x = getTrueOrFalseValue()) { ... }
```

But ES6 introduced `let` and `const` keywords, which declare variable accessible only in block-scope. Why aren't you allowed to use it in if/while conditions? For example:

```
if (let x = getTrueOrFalseValue()) { ... }
```

I find this pretty cool, because it doesn't spoil function scope with unused variables and allows to use them only in if/while block scope.

Comment: This is one of the question you have to answer with: It's a design choice.

Comment: You better ask this [TC39](http://www.ecma-international.org/memento/TC39.htm).

Comment: [`let (x = get…()) { }` blocks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#let_blocks) were considered but deemed unuseful.

Comment: @CodeiSir, I think that's, unfortunately, the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is impossible, because let can be only used as a statement, not as an expression. If you try (let f = 3); you also get an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is closest could get , here

```
function getTrueOrFalseValue() {
  return true
}

if (!(x = void 0)) {
  let x = getTrueOrFalseValue();
  if (x) {
    console.log(x)
  }
}
```

---

```
function getTrueOrFalseValue() {
  return true
}
if (!(this["x"]) || !(x)) {
  let x = getTrueOrFalseValue();
  if (x) {
    console.log(x)
  }
}
```

Comment: jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w0dptr37/ , https://jsfiddle.net/w0dptr37/1/

Comment: These will both throw an exception in real ES6

Comment: If you want a block, why not just use a block instead of a nonsensical if-statement?

Comment: @Bergi Tried at chromium 49, no exceptions thrown. Does chromium 49 expose "real ES6" ?

Comment: @Bergi _"If you want a block, why not just use a block instead of a nonsensical if-statement?"_ https://jsfiddle.net/w0dptr37/2/ , https://jsfiddle.net/w0dptr37/3/

Comment: Yes, like that, though you don't need to wrap your block in semicolons